# Using .click() with rel=noreferrer

Tags: jquery, html

i have a link with an ID with the rel=noreferrer property (in case you dont know, this means that the user will go to the href value, and the destinatary site won't know that they came from my site).

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="mylink" rel="noreferrer">click here</a>
```

If i use this jquery command, will the "rel" property still work?

```
$('#mylink').click();
```

Comment: Note that even the latest versions of IE and Firefox don't follow this standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `rel="noreferrer"` isn't respected by most browsers
2. Calling `$('#mylink').click();` won't do anything (not open the link). This would only trigger any appended javascript event handlers but not trigger the same action as a real user click

Comment: then, how can i load a link to an iframe with jquery?

Comment: a link to an iframe. What is that? Either it is a link or it is an iframe. What is supposed to happen. Should a new window open (or the current be reused) and the url from the href be opened or should the url from the href be displayed inside the current page in an iframe?

Comment: i already found out how to do this: window.open(url,'iframe-id-here');

Comment: Well had you asked from the beginning how to open a new window programmatically I could have told you an hour ago